# Will the temperature in equator lower when sunlight is block by asteriod ring?

Tags: science-based, planets, climate

I am trying to figure out the climate on my planet.  If there is an asteroid ring around the equator will it cool down the equator? And if it does cool down will the planet still be habitable?

My planet setup

1. The planet has no axis tilt and a circular orbit.(no season change)
2. Same day/night cycle as earth.
3. One moon.
4. Asteroid ring blocking sunlight cause the equator line to be in a
   total solar eclipse.
5. No land mass along the equator only sea.
6. There are three continents, one on the north hemisphere others on
   the south. The first one lies in between north polar and mid-latitude
   cell area. The second one is south-west from the first one and lies in
   between mid-latitude and Hadley cell area.
7. Third one is south-east from the first one and lies in the Hadley cell
   area.

Comment: How scientifically accurate do you want this? You will have a very hard time arranging the asteroid belt to create a permanent total shadow on the equator.

Comment: Well, it just an idea for my novel. So i just it want to confirm that the climate i imagine dont go the opposite of will happen. I don’t have any astrology background, so let said the asteroid somehow form that way.
Ps. sorry for my bad grammar, I'm from Thailand.

Answer (score 1):

an asteroid belt would hardly cause total eclipses. To obscure the sun you need, in case of the Heart, objects as big as half degree (like the Moon).

With a scientifically plausible asteroid belt (thick few meters at best) you would need the Sun to be far far away, so that it looks nothing more than a slightly bigger star. But in that case the influence of the eclipse on the planet climate would be, again, negligible.

Comment: so that mean having asteroid ring wont affect climate or sunlight. then, will it atleast shine at night?

Comment: I think it's much more likely to have an effect with a red dwarf. They are smaller on the sky than our sun and the energy they give off is much lower. @Arm definitely, there will be a portion of the ring that's gonna be on the shadow of the planet, but you should be able to see the bright portions from almost everywhere.